# Unexpected behavior for adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

I'm wondering why my UILabel isn't resizing the font correctly when the `numberOfLines` is set to 1. I have a playground set up with the code below:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let labelFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let label = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)
label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
label.text = "Something that's pretty long"

label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

label.numberOfLines = 1
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
let view = UIView(frame: frame)
view.backgroundColor = .white

view.addSubview(label)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

And this is the result [image: No font shrinking]

However, when I change the `numberOfLines` to 2 the font shrinks just like I'd expect:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let labelFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
let label = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)
label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
label.text = "Something that's pretty long"

label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

label.numberOfLines = 2   // <<<<<< this is the only change
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
let view = UIView(frame: frame)
view.backgroundColor = .white

view.addSubview(label)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

And here's the result:
[image]

What's going on here? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm it looks like this is just a bug in Playgrounds. If I add this line

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
```

everything works as expected. Actually, ANY of these work:

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

the one that doesn't work (and is also the default) is

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

When I tried this in a real simulator everything looked good, so I assume I just ran into a Playgrounds bug.